# How to randomly generate ANSI colors in Bash/Perl?

Tags: bash, perl

I want to generate ANSI colors randomly. It needs two features.

- Generated randomly
- Choice to generate from a specific color type e.g. randomly generate different shades of only grey or only green.

Comment: Is this a program request or is this a question? This question also shows no research and no attempt made by the asker.

Comment: This is at least three questions: generating random values, changing output colors, and doing this in `bash` or `perl`. You're going to have to show some research effort  and narrow this down a bit.

Comment: You don't appear to have asked a question, and seem to be expecting someone to do your job for you. Stack Overflow is about asking for help with fixing code that you've written and are struggling to get working. It's not a place where you can just dump a requirement and a solution magically pops out. You would get a far better response if you had appeared to make even the slightest effort on your own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In bash, you need to use color escape sequences with `echo -e`

**random_colors.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

TXT='the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.'
WORDS=( $TXT )
for WORD in "${WORDS[@]}"; do
    let "i=$RANDOM % 256"
    echo -en "\e[38;5;${i}m$WORD \e[0m";
done;
echo
```

Running this 10 times:

```
for i in `seq 1 10`; do bash random_colors.sh; done
```

**Output**

[image: Bash Color Output]

To get a particular palette, you will need to restrict the set of color numbers.

[ANSI Escape Codes for Colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors)

[Colors and Formatting](http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting)