# Stream shell output to web front end

Tags: vue.js, django-rest-framework

I'm looking to present the realtime output of a long running shell command running on a backend server including ANSI escape code rendering, much like how GitLab shows the output of a CI pipeline. For example: [image: Example]

Are there any existing libraries or frameworks that can provide this functionality? I would anticipate the frontend would retrieve the output from the backend via using REST calls in a loop, websockets, or similar. It looks like [jQuery Terminal Emulator](https://terminal.jcubic.pl) is close, but I am not looking to have an interactive terminal. The application's stack is currently using Django Rest Framework on the backend and Vue.js on the frontend.

Comment: Is this supposed to be instead of a ssh'ing into the backend?

Comment: SSH could potentially be the mechanism, but I would need a way initiate the ssh from the frontend, and then to present the output as it occurs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a pretty broad question, but a fun one. I found it difficult to provide an answer to this purely in terms of code, but perhaps you will find my answer useful nonetheless.

There are a couple of ways of achieving this:

1. Convert ANSI strings to HTML and send them to clients
2. Send the ANSI strings to the client and ask them to convert it

I opted for the second since you seem to be using Python in the backend, and I don't really know Python web programming to give you a full example. In this case, option 2 restricts the amount of code you will have to replicate in Python to get the functionality shown below.

You can find a full-fledged example with frontend and backend (NodeJS) code [here](https://github.com/gurupras/node-shell). The backend is simply a websocket server that pipes output of a command to incoming connections.

For the output, I  tried using `apt update` and `top`, but `apt update` will not render color output when invoked from NodeJS and `top` would complain about missing `tty`. Instead, I decided to use a simple shell script that generates strings with random ANSI colors. Most of this logic was borrowed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38392147/1761555).

The frontend is an extremely simple `Console` VueJS component which I've described below. All of the heavy-lifting is done by the [ansi_up](https://github.com/drudru/ansi_up) library and I simply use it's output directly as the HTML content of the component.

```
<template>
  <div class="console" v-html="html">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import AnsiUp from 'ansi_up'

export default {
  name: 'shell',
  props: ['socket'],
  data () {
    return {
      ansi: undefined,
      content: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
    html () {
      // Ensures we have some semblance of lines
      return this.ansi.ansi_to_html(this.content).replace(/\n/gm, '<br>')
    }
  },
  watch: {
    socket () {
      this.socket.on('data', data => {
        this.content += data
      })
      this.socket.send('ready')
    }
  },
  beforeMount () {
    this.ansi = new AnsiUp()
  },
  updated () {
    // auto-scroll to the bottom when the DOM is updated
    this.$el.scrollTop = this.$el.scrollHeight
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.console {
  font-family: monospace;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
</style>
```

Comment: This is a great answer. You are right that my question was broad, and at best I was hoping for some library recommendations. But providing a full-fledged example, using Vue no less, is fantastic.